# Calendar button not shown on result page of jsf code

Tags: javascript, jsf, calendar, richfaces

I am a new learner of JSF. I am trying to implement a sample calendar function, but not able to get the calendar button after running the xhtml page. Could anyone please tell me the reason for the same.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
          "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:a="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/passthrough"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:a4j="http://richfaces.org/a4j"
    xmlns:rich="http://richfaces.org/rich">
<h:head>
    <title>Date and Time Picker</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        Name : <h:inputText id="name" value="#{datePicker.name}"  
        a:placeholder="What's your name" />

        Date : <h:inputText id="date" value="#{datePicker.myDate}"  
        a:placeholder="What's your DOB" />  

        <rich:calendar value="#{datePicker.myDate}" id="myDate" popup="false"  datePattern="d/M/yy HH:mm"  buttonLabel="OpenCalendar" 
                cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" />
            <br/>
        <h:commandButton value="Submit" action="response" />


    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: "not able to get the calendar button" means what? Tell us what you're expecting to happen and what is actually happening.

Comment: Sorry for the unclearness of my question. I have attached an image but I think its not visible. I want to have a text box for date. After a click on the box I should get a calendar.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console? If you check the generated HTML what does the calendar look like?

Comment: Thats the thing. I am not getting any calendar :( No errors in console

Comment: Again "not getting any calendar" is not a helpful description of the problem. Are you saying there are no HTML tags generated for the calendar?

Comment: I am only getting the input text(Date). Clicking on the input text Calendar should open, right? the same calendar is not displayed when am clicking on the input text .    <rich:calendar value="#{datePicker.myDate}" id="myDate" popup="false"  datePattern="d/M/yy HH:mm"  buttonLabel="OpenCalendar" 
                cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" />  is not working

Comment: Calendar comes with its own input field but you've got `popup="false"` so the calendar should be visible by default. You still haven't answered me what the HTML looks like.

Answer (score 0):

After RichFaces libraries where added into the project it is necessary to register them in project web.xml file. Add following lines in web.xml:

```
<!-- Plugging the "Blue Sky" skin into the project -->

<context-param>

   <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>

   <param-value>blueSky</param-value>

</context-param>



<!-- Making the RichFaces skin spread to standard HTML controls -->

<context-param>

      <param-name>org.richfaces.CONTROL_SKINNING</param-name>

      <param-value>enable</param-value>

</context-param>



<!-- Defining and mapping the RichFaces filter -->

<filter> 

   <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name> 

   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 

   <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class> 

</filter> 



<filter-mapping> 

   <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name> 

   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>

   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>

   <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>

   <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>

</filter-mapping>
```

Comment: Yes I have registered the richfaces libraries, but still I am not getting the desired output